# SQL configure linked sever with domain user impersonation - kerberos / delegation requirements?

Tags: sql-server

I am configuring the linked server (via SSMS UI) on Svr1 to be able to query Svr2.

In the permissions I have added domain account (mydomain/myuser1) and check marked impersonate.

The mydomain/myuser1 is present on the Svr2 with read permissions to required databases.

What in terms of kerberos or delegation do I need to configure to complete the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The domain account has to be trusted for delegation in the AD, and you need to register SPN (service principle name). There's a diagnostic tool from Microsoft to troubleshoot kerberos related connectivity issues that can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046

Comment: Does this action need to be performed on the SvrA or SvrB? And where does that tool need to be run?